# ValueError at /adding-url-patterns-for-views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to allow user to post answer and comments to a particular bloq question
Q&A

Error displayed:

```
ValueError at /adding-url-patterns-for-views

Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x04A5B370>>": "PostAnswer.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.
```

Here is my model

```
class PostQuestion(models.Model):
    """ Model for posting questions """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, max_length=250)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('date published',
        auto_now_add=True)
    text_content = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail_view', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class PostAnswer(models.Model):
    """ Model for answering questions"""
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        PostQuestion,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comments',
    )
    text_content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('published', auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'comment by {} on {}'.format(self.user, self.question)
```

Here is my views.py on an app

```
class Index(ListView):
    queryset = PostQuestion.objects.all()
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 10

def detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(PostQuestion, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.all()
    #  comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.question = post
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', slug=slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    context = {'post': post,
              'comments': comments,
              'form': form}
   return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

My App form:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text_content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = PostAnswer
        fields = ['text_content']
```

My urls.py view for the app

```
from .views import detail, ask, Index
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    # path('<slug:slug>/comment', add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    path('ask/', ask, name='ask'),
    path('<slug:slug>', detail, name='detail_view'),
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Here is the html template for the comment

```
<!--------Display a form for users to add a new comment------->
    <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Comment</button>
    </form>
```

This is all of code that I think you need to know the problem. I don't know if the problem can be caused for database or why are not all instructions in the views.

If you can help me, thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the field is `question`, not <s>`post`</s>, so you should rewrite the logic to:

```
new_comment.question = post
```

This will however still raise an error, since the `user` field is not filled in either.

Using `commit=False` is however not a good idea, since then the form can no longer save many-to-many fields. As far as I can see, there are at the moment no many-to-many fields, but nevertheless, if you later add such fields, you have to rewrite the logic. You can improve the view to:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(PostQuestion, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.question = post
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('page:detail_view', slug=slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: I got a `ValueError at /adding-url-patterns-for-views

Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x04D375F0>>": "PostAnswer.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.`

Comment: @GabrielUsen: please edit the question with the *full* traceback.

Comment: @GabrielUsen: well likely your `user = ...` does not refer to a `User`, but to the `CustomUser`, so then you need to alter the `form.instance.user = ...` line to pass the `CustomUser` of the logged in user...